# test C program with some inputs

Tags: c, testing, text, input

I wrote a program in C and I want to try it with some inputs. The inputs
are not numbers so I can't use a for loop or something like this in the code.

So I want to write a file with inputs and give it to the program so it will take every time (it waits to input) 1 line from the text file or something like this, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it i spossible.

Comment: I think the first few sentences [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you are looking for unit testing. Please google that. There are a variety of frameworks to do this

Comment: Just loop on some [IO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) operation, perhaps [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) then use [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques

Comment: Sure it is possible. I sometimes create a helper function which creates test files which will be read by my program.  Try learning about IO as @BasileStarynkevitch mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program reads input from `stdin` - i.e. if you're using a function like `gets` or `scanf` to get your input -  you can achieve what you're asking about by using input redirection. Let's say you create a file called `test_input.dat` which contains your test data. If this file and your program reside in the same directory, you can change to that directory using

```
cd \your_directory
```

and then run your program, telling it to read input from `test_input.dat` by doing the following:

```
your_program < test_input.dat
```

This will cause your program to read data from test_input.dat instead of from the terminal, and should work the same for most common operating systems (Windows or Unix variants such as Linux, etc).

Best of luck.